# Trying to change GID on AIX server

Tags: aix, group

I am trying to change GID on Unix server "AIX".

I want to change `mygroupname:!:79002:` from group GID from `79002` to `79003`. I have permission to use sudo `/usr/bin/chgroup`.

I have tried everything, but I am still not able to change it.

Comment: what is the exact error message?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you use,

`chgroup id=79003 mygroupname`

If that doesn't work, is 79003 already in use?